# Two confusion matrices

Tags: machine-learning, contingency-tables, confusion-matrix, type-i-and-ii-errors

In a machine learning context, I am working on a binary classification problem. There is a source of truth $T$ for labels, and a labeling process $A$ which is not perfect and makes errors compared to $T$, according to a confusion matrix $C_{TA}$. There is then a second labeling process $B$, and a second confusion matrix $C_{AB}$ *between $A$ and $B$*.

Is it possible to calculate $C_{TB}$ from $C_{TA}$ and $C_{AB}$? If so, what would that calculation be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to calculate $C_{TB}$ from $C_{TA}$ and $C_{AB}$ alone.

As a counter-example, here are two trivial datasets which have the same confusion matrices $C_{TA}$ and $C_{AB}$, but have different $C_{TB}$.

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(matrix(
  c(rep(c("T","A","B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("!T","A","B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("T","!A","B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("!T","!A","B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("T","A","!B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("!T","A","!B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("T","!A","!B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("!T","!A","!B"), times = 1)),
  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
table(dat1$X1, dat1$X2)
#>     
#>      !A A
#>   !T  2 2
#>   T   2 2
table(dat1$X2, dat1$X3)
#>     
#>      !B B
#>   !A  2 2
#>   A   2 2
table(dat1$X1, dat1$X3)
#>     
#>      !B B
#>   !T  2 2
#>   T   2 2

dat2 <- data.frame(matrix(
  c(rep(c("T","A","B"), times = 2),
    rep(c("!T","A","B"), times = 0),
    rep(c("T","!A","B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("!T","!A","B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("T","A","!B"), times = 0),
    rep(c("!T","A","!B"), times = 2),
    rep(c("T","!A","!B"), times = 1),
    rep(c("!T","!A","!B"), times = 1)),
  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
table(dat2$X1, dat2$X2)
#>     
#>      !A A
#>   !T  2 2
#>   T   2 2
table(dat2$X2, dat2$X3)
#>     
#>      !B B
#>   !A  2 2
#>   A   2 2
table(dat2$X1, dat2$X3)
#>     
#>      !B B
#>   !T  3 1
#>   T   1 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If we are able to assume that $P(B|A,T) = P(B|A)$, that is, the probability of $B$ being positive is independent of the true value of $T$ given the value of the first classifier $A$, then we can find the joint distribution of $T, A, B$ from $C_{TA},C_{AB}$, and from that find $C_{TB}$. This assumption is not testable from the two confusion matrices, and would need to be evaluated via domain knowledge.

Suppose the two matrices are

$$
C_{TA} = \begin{bmatrix} 
& !A & A \\
!T & a & b \\
T & c & d
\end{bmatrix}\\
C_{AB}= \begin{bmatrix} 
& !B & B \\
!A & e & f \\
A & g & h
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $a + c = e + f$ and $b + d = g + h$. If $P(B|A,T) = P(B|A)$, then the number of observations which are $TAB$ will be $\frac{h}{g+h}(d)$. That is, the 2nd classifier takes the $d$ observations that were $TA$ and classifies them as $B$ with proportion $h/(g+h)$. Similarly the number of observations which are $T!AB$ will be $\frac{f}{e+f}(c)$. Combining gives the number of observations which are $TB$, $\frac{h}{g+h}(d) + \frac{f}{e+f}(c)$. Carrying on gives the desired matrix.

$$
C_{TB}= \begin{bmatrix} 
& !B & B \\
!T & \frac{e}{e+f}a + \frac{g}{g+h}b & \frac{f}{e+f}a + \frac{h}{g+h}b  \\
T & \frac{e}{e+f}c + \frac{g}{g+h}d & \frac{f}{e+f}c + \frac{h}{g+h}d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This confusion matrix may have non-integer entries, but it's elements are positive and add up to $a+b+c+d$.

Note again that this assumes $P(B|A,T) = P(B|A)$, which is not testable from $C_{TA}$ and $C_{AB}$. This assumption could be plausible if the second classifier is naive to the original classifier's purpose, and is strictly trying to predict the result of the first classifier. For example, if the second labeling process is trying to transmit the classification from A to a third party without making errors.

Comment: But here, you are starting from an arbitrary joint P(T,A,B), then finding P(T,A), P(A,B)  and P(T,B). The actual situation is not quite that: P(T,A) and P(A,B) are given first and independently. The joint P(T,A,B) would have to be retrieved from P(T,A) and P(A,B), no?

Comment: @Frank The joint P(T,A,B) cannot be found from P(T,A) and P(A,B) without more information, as this example demonstrates. Assuming some sort of statistical independence would be sufficient information for a unique solution to exist. But that assumption seems unreasonable to me. Do you have a specific independence assumption in mind?

Comment: indeed, not sure there is a reasonable independence assumption - How would we decide that? This problem arises in practice for me, with 3 teams of labelers, T being considered "source of truth", but A and B being entirely separate.

Comment: I did a simulation in python, but in my case, I first drew a binary random sample according to P(T), then depending on that value, drew another binary sample according to P(A|T), then drew yet another sample according to P(B|A). Then I tallied the results and grouped them by values of T. I realize that this is quite different, it probably calculates P(B|T) - but what do you think of that procedure?

Comment: @Frank In general these assumptions will be untestable without further information than the two tables provide. What you've simulated is the situation where B is independent of T given A: P(B|A,T) = P(B|A). That assumption would be enough to work, although it seems unlikely to be true in practice. I can edit my answer to give a method for that situation.

Comment: Going back to the practical situation, we have samples "approved" by team T, then reviewed by team A and we measure the first confusion matrix, but then we need to use another team B, for which we can measure the second confusion matrix (between A and B). The question is how to evaluate team B w.r.t. team T. Further practical considerations are that team T is too busy to label more data. All we can do is "quality test" B w.r.t A and then try to infer something about B, if possible. The samples we send to all those teams are all disjoint. Does that help?

Comment: @Frank I added an explanation of how to do the calculation if there is independence, but I think it's unlikely to be applicable to your situation. If Team B doesn't care about the existence of Team T, and is instead trying to emulate Team A's results, then independence is probably reasonable. If Team B knows the true purpose of the classification and is actually trying to emulate Team T, then this method will likely underestimate the performance of Team B. If Team B has extra time and this quality information is essential, perhaps they could try to label data previously labelled by Team T?

Comment: @Thanks David! Understood - Ideally, I should grab a sample to measure Team B against Team T directly.

Comment: One more thing - would you have a favorite textbook reference that would be relevant here? I'm not fully understanding "independence" in particular. In this case, teams T, A and B all 3 have the same objective. Team A was trained by team T. Team B only knows the common objective: they all know the "policy" to label samples. But the samples the 3 teams see are all different. I have a hard time translating this practical situation into a dependence/independence claim. Any reference to learn how to do that would be helpful.

Comment: Now I think that my T, A and B are anything but independent - since they are all three passing judgements on the samples based on the _same_ policy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136667/discussion-between-david-luke-thiessen-and-frank).